# Efficient counting of an association’s association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

In my app, when a `User` makes a `Comment` in a `Post`, `Notifications` are generated that marks that comment as unread.

```rb
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :comment

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications
```

I’m making an index page that lists all the posts for a user and the notification count for each post *for just that user*.

```rb
# posts controller
@posts = Post.where(
    :user_id => current_user.id
  )
  .includes(:notifications)

# posts view
@posts.each do |post|
  <%= post.notifications.count %>
```

This doesn’t work because it counts notifications for all users. What’s an efficient way to do count notifications for a single user without running a separate query in each post?

Answer (score 1):

[Found a solution!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878865/241292)

```
# posts controller
@posts = Post.where(… 
@notifications = Notification.where(
            :user_id => current_user.id,
            :post_id => @posts.map(&:id),
            :seen => false
        ).select(:post_id).count(group: :post_id)

# posts view
@posts.each do |post|
  <%= @notifications[post.id] %>
```

Seems efficient enough.

Comment: That solution works but it'll get more inefficient the more posts you have ..

current_user.posts.select('posts.id, posts.title, count(notifications.id)').join('left join notifications n on n.post_id = posts.id').where('n.id is null OR n.user_id = ?', current_user.id).group('posts.id')

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
@posts=Post.joins(:notifications).where('notification.user_id' => current_user.id)
```

Where `notification.user_id` is the id of the notification of current_user

Comment: Downside is that this eliminates the eager loading I believe the OP was attempting to use.

Comment: Won’t this produce posts with *just* unread comments? I want all posts with optional notification counts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a small class to encapsulate the logic for a collection of notifications:

```
class NotificationCollection
  def self.for_user(user)
    new(Notification.where(user_id: user.id))
  end

  def initialize(notifications)
    @notifications = notifications
  end

  include Enumerable
  def each(&block)
    @notifications.each(&block)
  end

  def on_post(post)
    select do |notification|
      notification.post_id == post.id
    end
  end
end
```

Then, on your controller:

```
@user_notifications = NotificationCollection.for_user(current_user)
@posts              = Post.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

Finally, on your view:

```
@posts.each do |post|
  <%= @user_notifications.on_post(post).count %>
end
```

That way, you only need to do a single notification query per user - not as performant as doing a `COUNT()` on the database, but should be enough if the notifications of a single user stay below the hundreds.

Comment: If I’m reading it correctly, this will produce a single count for the user? I’d prefer a count for each post (for that user).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you mean. Why is making multiple counts better?

Comment: I’m making a posts listing page in a thumbnail grid layout. I want to put a badge on top of thumbnails that contain unread notifications inside them. It’s more direct.

Comment: (Sorry about the confusion; I’ve clarified the original post.)

Comment: Oh, I took 'count' on your comment to mean a database count; sorry about the confusion too. My solution allows you to count the number of notifications on each post individually.